# Combine Total costs

Tags: sql

Fairly new to SQL and attempting to build a query which is "supposed to" grab all clients and combine their transactions and shipping QTY.  Unfortunatly I am not able to find a way to just SUM the data into one row per client.

```
Use Test
set NOCOUNT ON

select CompanyName, (SUM(t.Quantity) * b.Cost) AS TotalCost,
SUM(t.Quantity) AS Qty
 FROM
    tblSFCOrder o
     join tblSFCClient c on o.ClientNumber = c.ClientNumber
    JOIN    tblSFCOrderTxn t ON o.OrderID = t.OrderID
    JOIN    tblSFCInventory i ON t.SKU = i.SKU
            AND o.ClientNumber = i.ClientNumber
     JOIN   tblSFCBox b ON i.BoxID = b.Id 
     JOIN   tblSFCShipment s ON o.OrderID = s.OrderID 

where o.StatusID = 4 and o.ClientNumber = 1486
and shipdate between    '2015-10-01 00:40:01.370' AND '2015-10-31        23:23:38.163'
group by
CompanyName, b.Cost
```

and the end result is

```
1.CompanyName   TotalCost   Qty
2.Client1        191.60     479
3.Client1        159.12     306
4.Client1        2.64       4
```

And I want is just

```
 1.CompanyName  TotalCost   Qty
 2. Client1      353.36     789
```

Comment: Can you remove the b.Cost field from your Group By clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CompanyName,
    SUM(t.Quantity * b.Cost) AS TotalCost,
    SUM(t.Quantity) AS Qty
FROM tblSFCOrder o
INNER JOIN tblSFCClient c
        ON o.ClientNumber = c.ClientNumber
INNER JOIN tblSFCOrderTxn t
        ON o.OrderID = t.OrderID
INNER JOIN tblSFCInventory i
        ON t.SKU = i.SKU
       AND o.ClientNumber = i.ClientNumber
INNER JOIN tblSFCBox b
        ON i.BoxID = b.Id
INNER JOIN tblSFCShipment s
        ON o.OrderID = s.OrderID
WHERE 
        o.StatusID = 4
    AND o.ClientNumber = 1486
    AND shipdate BETWEEN '2015-10-01 00:40:01.370' 
                     AND '2015-10-31 23:23:38.163'
GROUP BY 
        CompanyName
```

Answer (score 2):

Change TotalCost to

```
 SUM(t.Quantity * t.Cost) AS TotalCost
```

and remove b.Cost from group by, only group by CompanyName

```
 group by CompanyName
```